# VB.NET Ajax UpdatePanel Unwanted Postbacks

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, vb.net

**GOAL**: Create a page that shows a loading image on button click, which disappears after the processing is complete.

**ISSUE**:  I have a page with an Ajax UpdatePanel that initially works correctly, displaying a loading page on button click, and then displays a GridView. However, after that happens, the page constantly refreshes and returns my GridView to its original state (I do some manual column adjustments `OnRowDataBound` like adding a legend row, merging some cells, cell background color changes, etc.)

The page is structured like so:

[image]

I am trying to include an Ajax UpdatePanel that shows a loading image after the `Generate Report` button is pressed.

On the content page, I essentially wrap the user control (report control shown in blue above and named `filterControl` below) and the content (gridview defined in .aspx page and bound in the code-behind) in the update panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelControls" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <uc:MultiLevelReportFilter ID="filterControl" runat="server" 
                                ReportTitle="Default Title"
                               InvisiblePanels="pnlMonths,pnlPeriods,pnlBusinessGroups,pnlDisplay,pnlBrands" 
                               DefaultAccountLevel="level4">
    </uc:MultiLevelReportFilter>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="thelink2" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateProgress" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div id="dvProgress" runat="server" style="background-color: aliceblue; left: 40%; position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 35%; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <div id="Div1" runat="server" style="background-color: #ffffff; border: 4px solid #DBE5F1; height: 100px; padding: 5px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 100px; width: 300px; z-index: 1002;">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Style="margin-top: 25px" Height="50px" Width="50px"
                                   ImageUrl="~/Images/New/ajax-loader.gif" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>


<% Gridview here composed of manually bound ItemTemplate columns %>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I wanted to add a trigger on the content page for `btnGenerate`, the `Generate Report` button seen in the user control, but the page errors out because `btnGenerate` is not actually on the page, rather it's in the control:

A control with ID 'btnGenerate' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'updatePanelControls'.

Is this structured incorrectly?  Should I have the Ajax on the user control, or content page?  I'm trying to follow this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but it doesn't have any examples with master pages and user controls.

**POSSIBLE REASON?**:  I should note that I am using an updatePanel on the master page to asynchronously update a label with the current time, like so:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Clock" runat="server" Interval="10000"></asp:Timer>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelClock" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="ClockLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Clock" EventName="Tick"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Is this what's causing the constant refreshes?

**EDIT**: I've added the `UpdateMode` property and set it to `Conditional` on the content page where I'm calling the report control.  However, the page is still refreshing incessantly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the entire page lifecycle will execute for every updatepanel postback.  Anything outside of that update panel will not be refreshed by what the server processed, but all the code will execute as if it were a full page postback.

Answer (score 0):

try javascript function

```
function myFunction() {
    var myVar = setInterval(function () { myTimer() }, 1000);
    function myTimer() {
        var d = new Date();
        var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
        document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML = "Current Time : " + t;
    }
```

this function call on form body

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```